# Whats wrong with this swift switch statement?

Tags: swift

Error given: Type 'String' does not conform to protocol ' IntervalType'

```
var value = "MELBOURNE"

func citycode(value:String) -> String{                
    switch (value){            
        case "MELBOURNE":
           return "MEL"
        case "TOKYO
           return "TOK"

    default :
        return "MEL"
    }
}
```

Comment: your case for `"TOKYO"` is not complete... thats all.

Comment: Close your "TOKYO" string with another " and :

Comment: When I paste your code into an Xcode project then I get the (very clear) error message "unterminated string literal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = "MELBOURNE"

func citycode(value: String) -> String {
    switch (value){
    case "MELBOURNE": return "MEL"
    case "TOKYO"    : return "TOK"
    default: return "MEL"
    }
}

citycode(value) // Prints "MEL"
```

your case for "TOKYO" is not complete... thats all.

Comment: Also, no need to wrap "value" with parens: `switch value { ... }`.